# "Update PCB Document" button is missing

Tags: pcb, altium

I worked on my schematic and I did the annotations and made my PcbDoc within the project, once I went to hit the Update PCB Document button from the "design" menu I realised that I don't have one (it's not greyed out, it's completely gone)
It was my first project with Altium designer and I was following the tutorials. I'm using the 21.2.2 version

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a project. You just have two files, one board layout, one schematic, but they are independent and not related to each other.

Comment: thank you so much